# Deployment of ASP.NET Boilerplate on Azure - Not redirecting after login

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-boilerplate

I'm working on a project that is built with ASP.NET Boilerplate. The template that I use is .NET Core with Angular, including Module Zero.
When I work locally (npm start), everything works as expected.

When I deploy prod build (ng build --prod) on Azure app loads the login screen but it does not redirect to home page after. I have hash location strategy set in root.module.ts.

```
(...{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }...)
```

Is there something else that needs to be set up, in some other .config or .ts file?

Edit:

After some investigation I have found out that if I comment out this code:

```
var initialUrl = UrlHelper.initialUrl;
if (initialUrl.indexOf('/login') > 0) {
    initialUrl = AppConsts.appBaseUrl;
}
location.href = initialUrl;
```

in file src\account\login\login.service.ts and adding this line:

```
location.href = AppConsts.appBaseUrl;
```

it works as expected. After successful login browser loads home page. But I would say that kills some of the functionality (redirecting to original requested page after login).

Comment: try useHash: true ..https://thinkster.io/tutorials/angular-2-routing-navigation

Comment: @AlperEbicoglu Did that, same effect. Nothing, after pressing the login button, login pop-up stays open, no redirect

Comment: ok. glad to see it works!